# What's best way to mock objects in swift within XCTest?

Tags: mocking, swift, xctest

What's best way to mock objects in swift within XCTest?
Is it just define classes inside functions with required functionality?
Or any better options exist?

Comment: can you provide some more information about the use case? people can mean so many different things when they say 'mock objects' - do you mean: (a) objects against which you can set an expectation and verify that the expectation was met? (b) dependent objects for which you can stub method implementations and set a return value? (c) just test doubles in general? maybe a bit more context, or an example, would help

Comment: all of those options (a,b,c)

Comment: I would like to see something like Mockito and OCMock support. The ability to stub out an object and test the original using expected behaviour in objects it touches is key.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Cuckoo](https://github.com/Brightify/Cuckoo), which is similar to Mockito.

Example Classes:

```
class ExampleObject {

    var number: Int = 0

    func evaluate(number: Int) -> Bool {
        return self.number == number
    }

}

class ExampleChecker {

    func check(object: ExampleObject) -> Bool {
        return object.evaluate(5)
    }

}
```

Example Test:

```
@testable import App
import Cuckoo
import XCTest

class ExampleCheckerTests: XCTestCase {

    func testCheck() {
        // 1. Arrange
        let object = MockExampleObject().spy(on: ExampleObject())
        stub(object) { object in
            when(object.evaluate(any())).thenDoNothing()
        }
        let checker = ExampleChecker()

        // 2. Action
        checker.check(object)

        // 3. Assert
        _ = verify(object).number.get
        verify(object).evaluate(any())
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(object)
    }

}
```

**Note** that the `MockExampleObject` class is auto-generated using custom `Run script` (in `Build Phases`), which `Cuckoo` docs mentions (in their install section).

Answer (score 0):

You can do protocol mocks and class mocks with [MockFive](https://github.com/carabina/MockFive).  It logs the methods that are called and the arguments passed in, and lets you stub methods at run-time, so you can just write one mock and configure it on a per-test basis.  I wrote an article about how to use it [here](http://pairtree.io/2016/01/10/mockfive-simple-reliable-mocks-in-swift/).

Comment: Daniel, welcome to the stack. You have a few answers going on this question. Try to delete one. There is a delete link. Nice answer on the other question where you really spelled it out. Try not to "link-only" an answer as they only get deleted or undesirable comments appear under them.

Comment: You should disclose that you are the author of this framework.